# How can I check the value that exists for the earliest date?

Tags: python, pandas, date

df:

| country | year | index |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Turkiye | 1992 | NaN |
| Spain | 1992 | NaN |
| US | 1992 | 1 |
| Turkiye | 1993 | 1 |
| Spain | 1993 | 1 |
| US | 1993 | 0 |
| Turkiye | 1994 | 1 |
| France | 1994 | 0 |
| Italy | 1994 | NaN |
| Turkiye | 1995 | 0 |

Here, for example, in 1992 Turkiye and Spain are NaNs but the index exists for the US. So I am only interested in the earliest date that the index exists for, the country does not matter in this case.

My code is:

```
a = np.where(df["Index"]!= None)
a["year"].min()
```

a is not a data frame, I think for this reason I am having a problem. How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.loc` with `.idxmin` after `.dropna`

```
df.loc[df.dropna()['year'].idxmin()]


country      US
year       1992
index       1.0
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is so compact and intuitive.

Comment: But what if there were other countries in 1992with the index values? What result would it give?

Comment: it would give the first value along the actual index @user19562955

Comment: no worries @user19562955 don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your question